# how can i predict products for new user ? Colaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

Hello this is example Collaborative Filtering - RDD-based API   https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html
But how can i predict  new user ?  If i want to recommend products to new user how should i did that ?

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/als/test.data")
val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, item, rate) =>
  Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})

// Build the recommendation model using ALS
val rank = 10
val numIterations = 10
val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)

// Evaluate the model on rating data
val usersProducts = ratings.map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
  (user, product)
}
val predictions =
  model.predict(usersProducts).map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
    ((user, product), rate)
  }
val ratesAndPreds = ratings.map { case Rating(user, product, rate) =>
  ((user, product), rate)
}.join(predictions)
val MSE = ratesAndPreds.map { case ((user, product), (r1, r2)) =>
  val err = (r1 - r2)
  err * err
}.mean()
println(s"Mean Squared Error = $MSE")

// Save and load model
model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
val sameModel = MatrixFactorizationModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myCollaborativeFilter")
```

Comment: Is this scala? in python you will do `sameModel .predict(testdata)` .

Comment: @Abdirahman yes it is scala,  sameModel.predict(testdata)   it work in scala thank you

Comment: You welcome, glad it help.